# robotframework with sencha extjs

Tags: extjs, robotframework

I will use robotframework to test an application that use the sencha extjs library,
my problem is that with this library the ids are generated dynamically every time
this add new components, therefore my robotframework script would change
constantly but this is a bad idea. somebody said me that other testing frameworks
it have plugins to this task but I cant found in robotframework.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using [Siesta](http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/). I no case add manual ids.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to access elements on the page, using the id is just one way. Assuming you're using Selenium2Library, you can use any of the following locators strategies (from the [Selenium2Library documentation](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html)):

```
Strategy        Example                                 Description
--------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------
identifier      Click Element | identifier=my_element   Matches by @id or @name attribute
id              Click Element | id=my_element           Matches by @id attribute
name            Click Element | name=my_element         Matches by @name attribute
xpath           Click Element | xpath=//div[@id='my_element']   Matches with arbitrary XPath expression
dom             Click Element | dom=document.images[56] Matches with arbitrary DOM express
link            Click Element | link=My Link            Matches anchor elements by their link text
partial link    Click Element | partial link=y Lin      Matches anchor elements by their partial link text
css             Click Element | css=div.my_class        Matches by CSS selector
jquery          Click Element | jquery=div.my_class     Matches by jQuery/sizzle selector
sizzle          Click Element | sizzle=div.my_class     Matches by jQuery/sizzle selector
tag             Click Element | tag=div                 Matches by HTML tag name
default*        Click Link    | default=page?a=b        Matches key attributes with value after first '='
```

Note that even though some examples (such as xpath) show the use of an id, an id may not be strictly required (except, obviously, for id= and identifier=). xpath is usually the strategy-of-last-resort, because you can reference pretty much anything in the document. For more about xpath you can start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great solution, so hopefully someone else can find a plugin or something that is easy to implement. However, if you do not find a different way, you can give every one of your Ext.js elements an ID manually by setting the "id" property on every one of your elements to a unique ID yourself. It would not take too much work, and if you named them something actually related to what they are, it would make the ID's more human readable.

From the Sencha docs:

> id : String
>
> The unique id of this component instance.
>
> It should not be necessary to use this configuration except for singleton objects in your application. Components created with an id may be >accessed globally using Ext.getCmp.
>
> Instead of using assigned ids, use the itemId config, and ComponentQuery which provides selector-based searching for Sencha Components analogous to DOM querying. The Container class contains shortcut methods to query its descendant Components by selector.
>
> Note that this id will also be used as the element id for the containing HTML element that is rendered to the page for this component. This allows you to write id-based CSS rules to style the specific instance of this component uniquely, and also to select sub-elements using this component's id as the parent.

Source: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-id

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Selenium2Library 1.7, users are now able to create their own custom locators. You could use this to create a location scheme based on ext's component query. So long as the overall structure of the app doesn't change that much, that may suffice. For more information on custom locators see the Selenium2Library [docs](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html).

I've started an add-on library for S2L on [github](https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-extjs) that you can check out for reference, but it isn't completely finished yet.

Also, Ext lets you place unique ids on components by simply specifying the id attribute. I would recommend applying ids to all elements which you want to interact with through your tests, thereby eliminating any need for complex behavior to automate the interface.